# Extracting JPEG/PNG/GIF Images from Data dump

Tags: java, png, jpeg, gif

I am provided with binary/hex dump of data from a disk. I am given the task to extract the images from it. It is a mixed dump of JPEG, PNG and GIF images.

You can find the data file at this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-x0saQ9lWTceEc4MXVLaXdXclE/view?usp=sharing).

The image headers and footers

```
jpg:
 header: FF D8 FF E0 xx xx 4A 46 49 46 00, footer: FF D9
png:
 header: 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A, footer: 49 45 4E 44 AE 42 60 82
gif:
 header: 47 49 46 38 39 61, footer: 00 3B
```

are perfectly intact in it. How do I extract the images using Java?

Comment: Yeah looks like looking for headers would be a really good start... now you can search for methods to do that.

Comment: I am actually unaware of how to deal with that data...

Comment: Search for: binary search in java

Comment: _"unaware of how to deal with that data..."_ What's the problem exactly? You mean you don't know what a `byteArray` is? Or you can't move within bytes? Or you can't make a `While` loop to search for values within bytes? Or maybe you can't even bring your hex dump into Java? What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you:

1. Open the input file as a `FileInputStream`.
2. Scan the input until you find one of the headers.
3. Open a new `FileOutputStream` for the output file, using the correct file extension for the image, and copy the content to that file, until you find the corresponding footer.
4. Close the output stream.
5. Start over from step 2, until you reach the end of the stream.
6. Close the input stream. Done.

Answer (score 0):

[Download](http://www.decuslib.com/decus/vmslt02a/net/jpegextractor.zip)  source code and bytecode of [Marco Schmidt's jpegextractor](http://www.decuslib.com/decus/vmslt02a/net/jpeg-extractor.html).

This will work for jpg.

For **png**,

replace `copyJpeg` function with

```
private void copypng(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws
    IOException
{
    boolean notFinished = true;
    long copiedBytes = 3;
    do
    {
        int v1 = in.read();
        if (v1 == 0x89) // marker
        {
            int v2 = in.read();
            if (v2 < 0) // end of file
            {
                out.write(0x82);
                copiedBytes++;
                notFinished = false;
            }
            else
            if (v2 == 0x49) // embedded png stream ended
            {
                // copy the end of stream marker
                out.write(0x49);
                out.write(0x45);
                out.write(0x4E);
                out.write(0x44);
                out.write(0xAE);
                out.write(0x42);
                out.write(0x60);
                out.write(0x82);
                copiedBytes += 2;
                notFinished = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // copy the two bytes, just a marker of the embedded png
                out.write(0x89);
                out.write(v2);
                copiedBytes += 2;
            }
        }
        else
        if (v1 == -1) // unexpected end of input file
        {
            notFinished = false;
        }
        else // just copy that value
        {
            out.write(v1);
            copiedBytes++;
        }
    }
    while (notFinished);
    totalBytes += copiedBytes;
    if (!quiet)
    {
        System.out.println(" (" + copiedBytes + " bytes)");
    }
    totalOutputFiles++;
    // close output stream
    try
    {
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        // ignore error when closing output stream
    }
}
```

and replace `process(InputStream in)` with

```
private void process(InputStream in) throws
    IOException
{
    int v1;
    do
    {
        v1 = in.read();
        if (v1 == 0x89)
        {
            int v2 = in.read();
            if (v2 == 0x50)
            {
                int v3 = in.read();
                if (v3 == 0x4E)
                {
                    int v4 = in.read();
                    if (v4 == 0x47)
                    {
                        int v5 = in.read();
                        if (v5 == 0x0D)
                        {
                            int v6 = in.read();
                            if (v6 == 0x0A)
                            {
                                int v7 = in.read();
                                if (v7 == 0x1A)
                                {
                                    int v8 = in.read();
                                    if (v8 == 0x0A)
                                    {
                                        OutputStream out = createNextOutputStream();
                                        out.write(v1);
                                        out.write(v2);
                                        out.write(v3);
                                        out.write(v4);
                                        out.write(v5);
                                        out.write(v6);
                                        out.write(v7);
                                        out.write(v8);
                                        copypng(in, out);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (v1 != -1);
}
```

For **gif**,
replace `copyJpeg` function with

```
private void copygif(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws
        IOException
    {
        boolean notFinished = true;
        long copiedBytes = 3;
        do
        {
            int v1 = in.read();
            if (v1 == 0x47) // marker
            {
                int v2 = in.read();
                if (v2 < 0) // end of file
                {
                    out.write(0x00);
                    copiedBytes++;
                    notFinished = false;
                }
                else
                if (v2 == 0x21) // embedded png stream ended
                {
                    // copy the end of stream marker
                    out.write(0x21);
                    out.write(0x00);
                    out.write(0x00);
                    out.write(0x3B);
                    out.write(0x00);
                    copiedBytes += 2;
                    notFinished = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // copy the two bytes, just a marker of the embedded png
                    out.write(0x47);
                    out.write(v2);
                    copiedBytes += 2;
                }
            }
            else
            if (v1 == -1) // unexpected end of input file
            {
                notFinished = false;
            }
            else // just copy that value
            {
                out.write(v1);
                copiedBytes++;
            }
        }
        while (notFinished);
        totalBytes += copiedBytes;
        if (!quiet)
        {
            System.out.println(" (" + copiedBytes + " bytes)");
        }
        totalOutputFiles++;
        // close output stream
        try
        {
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            // ignore error when closing output stream
        }
    }
```

replace `process(InputStream in)` with

```
private void process(InputStream in) throws
    IOException
{
    int v1;
    do
    {
        v1 = in.read();
        if (v1 == 0x47)
        {
            int v2 = in.read();
            if (v2 == 0x49)
            {
                int v3 = in.read();
                if (v3 == 0x46)
                {
                    int v4 = in.read();
                    if (v4 == 0x38)
                    {
                        int v5 = in.read();
                        if (v5 == 0x39)
                        {
                            int v6 = in.read();
                            if (v6 == 0x61)
                            {
                                OutputStream out = createNextOutputStream();
                                out.write(v1);
                                out.write(v2);
                                out.write(v3);
                                out.write(v4);
                                out.write(v5);
                                out.write(v6);
                                copygif(in, out);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (v1 != -1);
}
```

and update the value of `outputSuffix` in `private void setDefaultArguments()`